# Can't erase everything (partition/data) on sdcard, even with dd

Tags: partitioning, dd, fdisk

I have a Kingston sdcard (16g) with partition and data written on it. here is the output of

```
root@victor-ss9:/home/victor# fdisk -l /dev/sdf
Disk /dev/sdf: 15.6 GB, 15560867840 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 474880 cylinders, total 30392320 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000cde21

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1            3072      266239      131584    6  FAT16
/dev/sdf2          266240    30392319    15063040   83  Linux
```

then I erased with dd:

```
root@victor-ss9:/home/victor# sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdf bs=8192
dd: error writing ‘/dev/sdf’: No space left on device
1899521+0 records in
1899520+0 records out
15560867840 bytes (16 GB) copied, 557,952 s, 27,9 MB/s
```

Then I fdisk again, and oh! surprise, NO CHANGE:

```
root@victor-ss9:/home/victor# fdisk -l /dev/sdf
Disk /dev/sdf: 15.6 GB, 15560867840 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 474880 cylinders, total 30392320 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000cde21

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1            3072      266239      131584    6  FAT16
/dev/sdf2          266240    30392319    15063040   83  Linux
```

files and partitions are still there! same for both card. I use this kind of external sdcard reader (usb3):

[image]

and here are my sdcard (the samsung seems to works well with dd erase)
[image]

Any idea about where the problem comes from? I've never seen data/partition so persistent...(usually I don't want to delete them and they get deleted...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, check if the external sdcard reader have option to set read only (sometimes is called "Lock") to the attached sd card. If this is set to read only, you need to change this first, then use the data replacement command in your post.

You can also use urandom for better data erase.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdX bs=8192
```

**If you cannot delete/create partitions with fdisk (or cfdisk) then it means that you sdcard is dead.**

Comment: I edited my question, because my samsung card just got correctly erased by the dd command. But not the samsung...so does it come from the sdcard ? I added the picture of the sdcard. I can't see any button to lock read-only mode, neither on the sdcard nor on the sdcard reader...

Comment: Try using cfdisk to remove partitions first. Then use the command from my comment.

Comment: I cannot delete/create new partitions with cfdisk. I deduce that my sdcard is dead. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Finally I used SD Card Formatter (https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/). It have the option to ignore any partitions, doesn't matter the file system format.
Good luck!

Comment: I'm wondering how it solved the problem for you, they don't provide a Linux version